# Update person picker column with more than one person using JSON formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I want to set values ​​for person fields based on choice field selection, is this possible?

I started with the code sample below:

```
"customRowAction": {
    "action": "setValue",
    "actionInput": {
        "MultiPersonColumnInteranalName": "=if(indexOf(@currentField.email , @me) > -1 , removeFrom(@currentField.email , @me) , appendTo(@currentField.email , @me) )"
    }
}
```

What I have now is this, but putting the emails in people1, people2, ... doesn't seem to work. How could I fill this field properly with multiple people.

[image]

I want the emails to be assigned when selecting the corresponding item from the list

[image]

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, [Value Field values in `actionInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-advanced#value-field-values-in-actioninput),

Multi value fields (choice or people fields) are special, as they need an *array value* to save multiple values.

So, I managed to update multiple selection people field like below:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "button",
    "txtContent": "Set Value",
    "customRowAction": {
        "action": "setValue",
        "actionInput": {
            "Name": "=appendTo(appendTo([$Name.email], @me), 'meganb@contoso.com')"
        }
    }
}
```

Where "Name" is internal name of people field in SharePoint list. You can get the internal name of your Image column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

---

**OR** you can use `split` operator like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "button",
    "txtContent": "Set Value",
    "customRowAction": {
        "action": "setValue",
        "actionInput": {
            "Name": "=split('gsanap@contoso.com;meganb@contoso.com;sdas@spexplorer.onmicrosoft.com', ';')"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any chance of doing this without clicking the button, but only after choosing an item from the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "after choosing an item from the list"? On click of item row? Default action on click of Title column is to Open the display form of List.

Comment: I edited my question see now, the function you put in the button is interesting, but I would like the action to be triggered when selecting an item in the status choice

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use `setValue` on selection of choices from choice column.